# DateAdd Function in Microsoft Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, dateadd

I am trying to implement the DateAdd function into my Microsoft Access 2010 form. I have a form that when the user inputs the date (property name called "txtStartDate", then I want the output in a different part to be 18 calendar days in the future (property name called "textEndDate").

I know the format will be

```
=DateAdd("d", 18, txtStartDate)
```

but how do I write it in VBA code to implement?

Comment: I believe you have your criteria in the wrong order see: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DateAdd-Function-63befdf6-1ffa-4357-9424-61e8c57afc19  so it should be `=DateAdd("d",18, txtStartDate)`

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you wish to set it after an update. Thus, use the *AfterUpdate* event of the start date:

```
Private Sub txtStartDate_AfterUpdate()

    Dim EndDate As Variant

    If IsDate(Me!txtStartDate.Value) Then
       EndDate = DateAdd("d", 18, Me!txtStartDate.Value)
    Else
       EndDate = Null
    End If
    Me!txtEndDate.Value = EndDate

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps somewhat, two declarations for the original date and the new date. Msgbox then shows them both here on different lines:

```
sub addingDate()
Dim txtStartDate As Date
Dim txtEndDate As Date
    txtStartDate = Now 'Or wherever you get this info from
    txtEndDate = DateAdd("d", 18, txtStartDate)
    MsgBox (txtStartDate & vbNewLine & txtEndDate)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're implicitly converting a textbox value from a String to a Date. You might want to add some checks like:

```
If IsDate(txtStartDate) Then
```

And you'll want to be particularly conscious of the behavior should your code be running on systems that have varying Regional Date settings for American/English/Japanese dates. That *might* require using a date-picker or some other date-validation on the control itself.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need VBA to do that, only an expression as *ControlSource* for that other textbox:

```
=DateAdd("d", 18, [txtStartDate])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
= DateAdd("d", 18, cdate(txtStartDate)
```